# Which theory could describe rate constant for photodissociation?

Tags: kinetics, photochemistry

I am considering photodissociation reactions and want to find an appropriate theory to describe how one could determine the rate constant. I know [Rice-Ramsperger-Kassel-Marcus (RRKM) theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRKM_theory) is for unimolecular reactions but I have only seen the theory applied to isomerization reactions. Could one use RRKM theory to describe the kinetics of photodissociation? What other theories would make sense to apply?